# Constrain extension with superclass

Tags: swift

Swift can’t convert my table to furniture. Do I have to use something like `is` in the where clause?

```swift
class Furniture {}
class Table: Furniture {}

extension Array where Element == Furniture {
    var material: String { print("material") }
}

let tables = [Table]()
tables.material() // error: '[Table]' is not convertible to 'Array<Furniture>'
```

Comment: instead of a class just create a protocol Furniture and add the  required properties like material. Then you just need to make a Table structure that conforms to Furniture

Comment: Btw each table should have its own material. You are trying to access it on the collection instead of its element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's a lot going on here:

- You're saying `var material` but then you try to call it like a function when you say `material()`.
- Your `var material` is a String but you neglect to return a String from its getter.
- You cannot say `Element == Furniture` because that makes the generic nongeneric. Change it to `:`.
- Your `table.material` returns a value but you are throwing it away.

So, taking all of that on board:

```
class Furniture {}
class Table: Furniture {}

extension Array where Element : Furniture {
    var material: String { return "Material" }
}

let tables = [Table]()
let s = tables.material
```

However, that merely allows your code to compile; as has been pointed out in the comments, what you are doing makes no sense of itself. You can give a Table a `material` but it is hard to see what it could mean to give an *array* of Table a `material`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: How would I constrain to a generic class? Like `extension Array where Element : Item<Furniture>` (leads to `error: property 'material' requires that 'Item<Table>' inherit from 'Item<Furniture>'`)

Comment: You seem to think there is some superclass-subclass relationship between `Item<Table>` and `Item<Furniture>`. There isn't.

Comment: I see. So I would have to copy and paste `var material: String { return "Material" }` to both extensions (`extension Array where Element : Item<Furniture>` and `extension Array where Element : Item<Table>`), right?

Comment: This is way off topic. You should not be using a generic at all. You should not be giving Array a new property. None of it makes sense. I’ve said what I’ve said. If you have a new question ask a new question.